# slickgrid total

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

In slickgrid, I put a total aggregator sum. It sums all the rows from that column (percents) and works fine. 
But now I am facing that I want only get the totals from the active percents. Column active is other column that contains 0 or 1.

In the column definition:

```
{id: "percent", name: "Percent", field: "percent", minWidth: 60, sortable: true, groupTotalsFormatter: sumTotalsFormatter, editor: Slick.Editors.Text}

function sumTotalsFormatter(totals, columnDef, id) 
{
  return "Total: " + Math.round(totals.sum[columnDef.field]) + "%";
}
```

The aggregators:

```
  dataView.setAggregators([
    new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Avg("percent"),
    new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("percent")
  ], false);
```

I have been trying different ways but no success (Putting a non showing second field to store only the active data, searching on how to modify an agreggator.. etc). Any idea?

Comment: please move your solution out to its own answer. Others may still try a different approach that you could find useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Well I solved crawling in Firebug and retesting several times. Here is my solution:
>
> ```
> function sumTotalsFormatter(totals, columnDef) 
> {
>   var suma      = 0;
>   //current group...
>   var groupo    = totals.group.value;
>   for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
>   {
>     if(data[i].active == '1')
>     {
> //data[i].us is the one who makes the groups...
>         if(groupo == 1 && data[i].us == '1')
>         {
>             suma += parseInt(data[i].percent);
>         }
>         else if(groupo == 0 && data[i].us == '0')
>         {
>             suma += parseInt(data[i].percent);
>         }
>     }   
>   }
>   return "Total: " + suma + "%"; 
> }
> ```