# SlickGrid add html in footer row column

Tags: jquery, html, css, typescript, slickgrid

I am trying to add html to a slickGrid footer column, basically I am totally the column and want it in the footer.

I am using serenity framework for the web application and it uses slickGrid.
I can calculate the totals of the column I am interested in, but I cannot set the value or anything for that matter into the footer row column.
The jQuery selector finds the footer row with my columns length [6].

How can I add this total into that location?

```
<div class="ui-state-default slick-footerrow-column l5 r5 align-center"></div>
```

```
var elemA = this.element.find(".slick-footerrow-column");

elemA.children().last().html("<font color='black'> T:" + this.orderTotal + "</font>");
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="ui-state-default slick-footerrow-column l5 r5 align-center">My Total</div>
```

I have searched here: [slickgrid-grand-totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357935/slickgrid-grand-totals).
And also here [slickgrid-total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346835/slickgrid-total).

Comment: that does sound like the [Footer Totals - Example](https://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-footer-totals.html)

Comment: @ghiscoding the method getFooterRowColumn(columnId); is not available in the slickGrid. I am not sure when that became available my current version looks like 2.2 and it is in the serenity framework - so upgrading it might pose some problems.

Comment: well then ask the Serenity project to update their version of SlickGrid. Being on an old version, you're missing out on a lot of new features like Frozen Column/Row, Row Detail, ... and many more. The other option might be to try to implement that method yourself if it's possible with public SlickGrid methods. Good Luck

Comment: Being open source, you could also find the getFooterRowColumn(columnId) method from the current SlickGrid and monkey patch it into your Slickgrid. Don't forget the current repo is https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

Comment: @BenMcIntyre Yes these are two options, but I was hoping for one of those ..here is the quick way, with out going through the long drawn out  process. There are a lot of really good coders who have more experience and insight than I do and sometimes someone has that simple solution.